# MOQ testing Email Service and unable to get back the value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, abstract-class

I am trying to test a Domain Service which is to send email after the order has been placed. This service has private methods so I called a method on the public interface which was calling this private service method. Issue is I cant seem to check CC on the email as this is in the private method. 
the only approach I know to figure this if that value was saved as an interface property etc but its not. see the code below.

```
     public int SendConsolidatedDespatchNotifications(int countOfWorkDays)
    {
        var sent = 0;
        var trackings = _despatchLineRepository.GetTrackingWithoutDespatchNotificationInPreviousWorkDays(countOfWorkDays);
        var trackingsWithinOrder = trackings == null
            ? new List<OrderLineTracking>()
            : trackings.Where(dl => dl.DespatchReference != null).ToList();
        trackingsWithinOrder.GroupBy(ot => ot.OrderKey).ForEach(
            ot =>
            {
                if (SendConsolidatedDespatchNotifications(ot))
                {
                    _despatchLineRepository.SetAsSent(ot.Select(ol => ol.DespatchLine));
                    sent++;
                }
            });

        return sent;
    }

     private bool SendConsolidatedDespatchNotifications(IGrouping<int, OrderLineTracking> orderTrackingLines)
    {
        if (orderTrackingLines == null)
            return false;
        if (orderTrackingLines.Key == 0)
            return false;
        if (orderTrackingLines.Any())
        {
            var firstLine = orderTrackingLines.First();
            var allOrderLines = _orderLineRepository.GetOrderLinesByOrderKey(firstLine.OrderKey);
            var partiallyDespatchedLines = FindPartiallyDespatchedLines(orderTrackingLines);
            var notDespatchedLines = FindNotDespatchedLines(allOrderLines, orderTrackingLines);
            return SendConsolidatedDespatchedEmail(firstLine.DespatchReference, orderTrackingLines, partiallyDespatchedLines, notDespatchedLines);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool SendConsolidatedDespatchedEmail(
        string poNumber,
        IEnumerable<OrderLineTracking> despatchedLines,
        IEnumerable<OrderLineTracking> partiallyDespatchedLines,
        IEnumerable<OrderLine> notDespatchLines)
    {
        //we just assume that one PO have always just one order
        var firstDespatchedLine = despatchedLines.First();
        var order = firstDespatchedLine.OrderLine.OrderHeader;
        if (order?.Customer == null)
            return false;

        var despatchGroups = new List<DespatchLineGroup>();
        despatchedLines.GroupBy(dl => dl.DespatchReference).ForEach(
            dl => despatchGroups.Add(
                new DespatchLineGroup
                {
                    DespatchReference = dl.Key,
                    DespatchedLines = dl,
                    TrackingWebLink = GetTrackingWebLinkFor(dl.First())
                }));

        var despatchNotificationEmail = new DespatchConsolidatedNotificationEmail(
            order.Customer,
            order,
            despatchGroups,
            CreateNotDespatchedItemsList(partiallyDespatchedLines, notDespatchLines));

        var ccCustomer = _customerRepository.GetByCostCentreIdentifier(order.CostCentreIdentifier, order.Customer.Key);

        var ccOnBasket = ccCustomer?.CostCentre; 

        if (ccOnBasket == null)
        {
            despatchNotificationEmail.To.Add(new EmailAddress(order.Customer.FullName, order.Customer.Login));
        }
        else
        {
            FillInSubaccountDetails(despatchNotificationEmail, ccCustomer, order, order.Customer, ccOnBasket);
        }

        despatchNotificationEmail.PopulateContentWithTags();
        despatchNotificationEmail.SendAfter = firstDespatchedLine.DespatchDate;
        despatchNotificationEmail.Save();

        _log.InfoFormat("Despatch email {0} for {2} sent to {1}", "DespatchConsolidatedNotificationEmail", order.Customer.Login, poNumber);

        return true;
    }

    private void FillInSubaccountDetails(
        EmailTemplate email,
        Customer ccCustomer,
        OrderHeader order,
        Customer masterAccount,
        CostCentre ccOnBasket)
    {
        //send notifications to CostCentre account, which is on basket
        email.To.Add(new EmailAddress(ccCustomer.FullName, ccCustomer.Login));

        if (ccOnBasket.ReceiveNotifications) //send notifications to master only if CC is set so
        {
            email.To.Add(new EmailAddress(masterAccount.FullName, masterAccount.Login));
        }

        if (order.OrderPlacedBy.HasValue) //PD-2140 Sending email to Purchaser as well
        {
            var purchaser = _customerRepository.Get(order.OrderPlacedBy.Value);
            if (purchaser?.Purchaser != null && purchaser.Purchaser.ReceiveNotifications)
            {
                email.To.Add(new EmailAddress(purchaser.FullName, purchaser.Login));
            }
        }


        if ( order.ApprovedBy != null)
        {
            var approver = _customerRepository.Get(order.ApprovedBy.Value);
            if(approver?.Approver != null &&  //has approver and its not MAH
               approver.Approver.ReceiveNotifications)
                email.To.Add(new EmailAddress(approver.FullName, approver.Login));
        }
    }

   //this inherits from EmailTemplate which has save method.
   public class DespatchConsolidatedNotificationEmail : EmailTemplate
     {
    public DespatchConsolidatedNotificationEmail() { }

    public DespatchConsolidatedNotificationEmail(
        Customer customer,
        OrderHeader orderHeader,
        List<DespatchLineGroup> despatchLines,
        List<NotDespatchedLine> notDespatchLines)
    {
        AddEmailData(customer);
        AddEmailData(orderHeader);
        AddEmailData(despatchLines);
        AddEmailData(notDespatchLines);
    }
}
    //below is the save method
    public int Save()
    {
        var manageSave = Configuration.Container.Resolve<IWantToManageSaving>();
        return manageSave.Save(this);
    }
```

Note Email implements a abstract class which is EmailTemplate not an interface..

I want to figure out which emailAddress has been added ?

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete (no closing brace). Is that all there is?

Comment: I have updated this and added complete code

Comment: You shouldn't test what this `private` method returns. You should test whether your `public` method does what it should. It would be easier if you've shown us the `public` method as well.

Comment: there are quite a few methods up the hierarchy before the private method gets hit. I am afraid there is not useful information in those public methods. 
the very first public method returns the int which just tells us if the email has been sent or not nothing more then that.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The only method that actually matters it the `public` method you are testing and its contract.

Comment: this is a business requirement to write the test cases for who receives the emails.
Business people dont know about the code. I think I have already got an idea about how I am going to implement this. I am going to create a public list in the service and add all the emailsaddress to the list as the program goes through the email flow. then I will be able to access that in the test for assert.

Comment: You shouldn't add stuff to your code that will be used only in tests.
My point is - if your method sends an email (that's all I got, since you refuse to actually share the method), you should check if the CCs in the sent email are set correctly. That's what you ultimately care about, not wether your `private` method works this way or that way. It's an implementation detail. If "business people don't understand the code", then especially they shouldn't care about your implementation, but rather if the email is sent with correct values set.

Comment: I see what you are saying and it makes sense to not add code specifically for tests. I have shared all the code now. 
I don't want to send the emails for testing, while I am trying to see what different types of people are added on the email CC list.

Comment: Okay, now there's more to work with. What does the `DespatchConsolidatedNotificationEmail.Save` method do?

Comment: save method is part of the EmailTemplate which is abstract class inherited by the DespatchConsolidatedNotificationEmail. I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

There are arguments pro and con unit testing private methods. I'll leave it up to you to decide if it's a good idea or not. Having said that you can use the `PrivateObject` class. Something along these lines:

```
Class c = new Class();
PrivateObject o = new PrivateObject(c);
var whatever = o.Invoke("FillInSubaccountDetails");
Assert.AreEqual(whatever, expected);
```

There is a problem here since your method returns void, there's no return value to assert. You may need to adapt your method?

Comment: as I mentioned in the question I am not testing this directly, I am calling a method which is public and that in turns ends up calling this method. I want to know if there is a way I can assert the value without having to modify the method itself?

Comment: I'm confused, what value are you trying to assert? And can you include the code for the public method?

Comment: No I cant add that to the public method, I want to check which email address is added to the email object, is it Master Account / Purchaser or Approver.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on all the code you provided:

Your `Save` method smells of bad practice. You shouldn't use an IoC container to manually resolve dependencies. If you had the `IWantToManageSaving` (I like the naming by the way :) ) injected via a ctor you could mock it in your test. If you had a `var savingManagerMock = new Mock<IWantToManageSaving>()`, you could then verify in your unit test  that the `Save` method was called with a correctly setup instance of `EmailTemplate`. Something like:

```
// ASSERT

savingManagerMock.Verify(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<EmailTemplate>(
    arg => arg.To.Contains(/* ... */));
```

Or something or the like, depends on the actual assertions you want.

Another way would be to abstract the construction of the `DespatchConsolidatedNotificationEmail` into a factory `IDespatchConsolidatedNotificationEmailFactory`, make it return a special mock of `DespatchConsolidatedNotificationEmail` and setup its `Save` method to, for example, save the current state of the `EmailTemplate` and then assert it. I would still lean towards the first solution, however.

On an ending note: as you can see testing this method is fairly complicated. That usually means it could be written better. In this case I see two red flags, first one is the explicit use of a `Container` which can always be avoided with dependency injection (manual resolution ain't no injection :P). Second is that this method is fairly complicated! It calls a lot of private methods and there's a lot of logic that can't be understood by a quick read through the method. You should consider splitting these private methods into maybe `internal` helper methods in another class that would be unit-tested separately. Then you could trust them when testing this public method, as they're basicaly a dependency at that point, setup mocks and just assert that correct `internal` methods are called and the method's contract is fulfilled.

Comment: I agree with you that this is fairly complicated logic. I like to idea of adding these methods to a different class so that the methods can be sperately testable. 
I am however not confident that I can resolve the dependency injection at this point as it could be more time consuming. Also if I add the helper classes should I keep them private or public ? I believe they would need to be public so that I can unit test them.

Comment: Also what do you think about creating another constructor so that  I can use that only for this instance?

Comment: If they're not going to be used outside the assembly, make them `internal`. You can test `internal` classes by using `[assembly: ExposeInternalsTo("YourQualifiedAssemblyName")]` in your `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Again, making things only used by tests is really bad. If you _really_ want to keep your code smelly and leave the manual resolution, maybe you could register the mock in the container as `IWantToManageSaving`?